# How to make APT assume yes and force yes for all installations in a Bash script

Tags: bash, apt, apt-get

I'm currently getting into Linux and want to write a Bash script which sets up a new machine just the way I want it to be.

In order to do that I want to install different things on it, etc.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have a setting at the top of the Bash script which will make APT accept all [y/n] questions asked during the execution of the script.

A question example I want to automatically accept:

`After this operation, 1092 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

I just started creating the file, so here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Constants

# Set APT to accept all [y/n] questions
>> some setting here <<

# Update and upgrade APT
apt update;
apt full-upgrade;

# Install terminator
apt install terminator
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`apt` is meant to be used interactively. If you want to automate things, look at `apt-get`, and in particular its `-y` option:

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>
> Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable
> situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install an
> unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then
> apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

See also `man apt-get` for many more options.

Comment: Cool, thanks that works - but would there be an option which I could set for apt-get so I dont have to write -y in every line ?

Comment: @Christian Just put everything in one `apt-get` command, it takes multiple packages: `apt-get install -y pack1 pack2 pack3`

Comment: @Christian: or see `man apt.conf`

Comment: I just did `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` and it worked with apt.

Comment: "apt is meant to be used interactively. If you want to automate things, look at apt-get" <- this saved me a headache. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With `apt`:

```
apt -o Apt::Get::Assume-Yes=true install <package>
```

See: `man apt` and `man apt.conf`

Answer (score 3):

If you indeed want to set it up once at the top of the file as you say and then forget about it, you can use the `APT_CONFIG` environment variable. See [`apt.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf).

```sh
echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes=yes" > /tmp/_tmp_apt.conf
export APT_CONFIG=/tmp/_tmp_apt.conf

apt-get update
apt-get install terminator
...
```

Comment: proper syntax is `APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up APT to assume 'yes' permanently as follows:

```
echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";\nAPT::Get::allow \"true\";" | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_no_prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to set it at the top of your script is to use this command:

```bash
alias apt-get="apt-get --assume-yes"
```

This will cause all subsequent invocations of `apt-get` to include the *--assume-yes* argument. For example, `apt-get upgrade` would automatically get converted to `apt-get --assume-yes upgrade` by Bash.

Please note that this may cause errors, because some *apt-get* subcommands do not accept the *--assume-yes* argument. For example, `apt-get help` would be converted to `apt-get --assume-yes help` which returns an error, because the help subcommand can't be used together with *--assume-yes*.

Comment: Why is there only one double quote near *"converted to apt-get"*? Should there be one at all?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, there shouldn't be a quote there, I updated the question. Thanks.